# Saleforce LWC websocket

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can anyone help with a sample solution for Saleforce LWC websocket?

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Websk extends LightningElement {
  let connection=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8787",['soap','json']);
   if ('WebSocket' in window){
    console.log("WebSocket is supported.");
    /* WebSocket is supported. You can proceed with your code*/
   } else {
      console.log("WebSockets are not supported.");
      /*WebSockets are not supported. Try a fallback method like long-polling etc*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Can I ask you to please read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/292487/edit) your question to add more detail. You are more likely to get a useful answer when your question explains what you are trying to do (what is the requirement), shows what you have already tried and explains the issue(s) you are facing.

Comment: Okay, sure. I will modify the queries accordingly.  I did not have basic working code sample for LWC with Websocket connection. Am a new SF developer. So I came for help here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported, which you can see in the [Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer). This is because security cannot be properly enforced with the client-worker model, which could cause undesirable or even malicious behavior. I'm sure it's not an unsolvable problem, but for now, the rules are, we can't have them. There's an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003Zv9QAE) for you to vote on. Also, the Locker API Viewer has a voting mechanism for unsupported APIs. Choose which type of worker you want to see supported.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply. So you mean to say that we can't establish a WSS connection from javascript code in Lightning Web Componnets(LWC). If we can establish a connection, can you please a share an example.

Comment: @GomathiHariharan No, we can't use WSS at this time.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!